# Install Sass on Mac

Tags: sass

I used brew to install sass on mac.
"Successfully installed sass-3.7.4
Parsing documentation for sass-3.7.4
Done installing documentation for sass after 2 seconds
1 gem installed".

But when I enter "sass -v", the result is as below:
-bash: sass: command not found

???

Answer (score 1):

Try to `brew info sass` to show the installation path of a package. After that you can bind saas alias manually by the resulting path

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Homebrew has changed the name to `node-sass`